# Navigation bar issue in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using navigation controller in my application. Mostly all controllers have navigation bar hidden false except in one controller. When I pop from that controller then navigation bar is shown weird and the bottom space of about navigation bar is left. Also when I do start editing or do some selection or something else the navigation bar becomes normal and the empty space is removed, but it remains till I don't do anything. I am using Xcode 5, and these happens in both iOS 6 and ios 7 not tested in iOS 5. In view Did disappear of that controller I do

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = FALSE;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

Also in view will appear of the other controller I have written

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = FALSE;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

In both the view auto layout is false as I need to change frame dynamically on different conditions. Please help.

Comment: did you try to add [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; in viewWillDisappear of the view controller with the hidden navigation bar ?

Comment: yes have written that in both view will disappear and view did disappear

Answer (score 3):

Use below code.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Use willAppear/Disappear instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i removed that white space by setting background color of the navigation bar view. like

```
[[[self navigationController] view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```